# Como mostrar los datos de una base de datos en una tabla en html y php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Soy nuevo en esto de php y html y quiero mostrar los datos en una tabla personalizada por bootstrap, este es mi codigo

```html
<?php

// Conectando, seleccionando la base de datos

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'usbw')

    or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());


mysql_select_db('hotel') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');



// Realizar una consulta MySQL
$query = 'SELECT id, nombre, apellido, telefono, dias, habitaciones FROM registro';

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());

?>

<table class="table table-striped">
   
  <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>NOMBRE</th>
   <th>APELLIDO</th>
   <th>TELEFONO</th>
   <th>ESTADIA</th>
   <th>HABITACION</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
 <td><?php $row['id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php $row['nombre'] ?></td>
    <td><?php $row['apellido'] ?></td>
    <td><?php $row['telefono'] ?></td>
    <td><?php $row['dias'] ?></td>
    <td><?php $row['habitaciones'] ?></td>
 
<?php} ?>
</table>
```

Comment: aquí aparecen los links que debes agregar en el header de tu html: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp  debes empezar por eso, luego debes generar una tabla como las que muestran aquí: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp

Comment: Los link ya los tengo agregado y los he usado en asp.net y todo me ha funcionado pero ahora me toca hacerlo en php y quiero utilzar el mismo diseño pero no se como hacer que los datos de la base de dato se muestren en las celdas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recuerda que el formato html. para tu documento de acuero con lo que quieres hacer con bootstrap.

Te recomiendo leer la documentación de php http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php, y ademas tratar de separar el código php de html por buenas practicas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Te recomiendo utilizar esta conección, la que utilizas ya no es la recomendada. 
$link = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hotel', 'root', ''); // el campo vaciío es para la password. 

?>

<table class="table table-striped">
   
  <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>NOMBRE</th>
   <th>APELLIDO</th>
   
  </tr>
  </thead>
<?php foreach ($link->query('SELECT * from registros') as $row){ // aca puedes hacer la consulta e iterarla con each. ?> 
<tr>
 <td><?php echo $row['id'] // aca te faltaba poner los echo para que se muestre el valor de la variable.  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['nombre'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['apellido'] ?></td>
 </tr>
<?php
 }
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero serte de ayuda.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Gracias esto fue de mucha ayuda, les agradezco la información publicada
Salu2